# Decrypting AES-128 with known regularly spaced single byte value

Tags: aes, brute-force-attack, decryption

How would knowing a clear byte value of the decrypted data affect a brute force attack on an AES-128 encrypted message ?
i.e. If I knew the 1st byte should decrypt to 0xff
OR I knew that every 100 Bytes should decrypt to 0xff ?
OR I knew every 100 2 bytes should decrypt to 0xff00 ?

Comment: I've linked to a question that explains brute forcing for known plaintext, but the simple answer is that AES - in a good mode of operation, is secure against known plaintext attacks. You cannot obtain the key (other than through brute force) with known plaintext and you cannot therefore decrypt the rest of the plaintext data.

Comment: We have confusion and diffusion paradigms where diffusion makes this useless i.e. same as knowing all.